# How to confirm that a more frequently labelled object is a better instance of the label

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

I have some data from a study where humans are shown an object and asked to select all words from a list that apply to the object. What I am trying to do is use the data to confirm that a particular object, $o_{1}$, is a better fit of a particular word, $w$ , than another object, $o_{2}$. I am trying to use hypothesis testing to confirm this, with a null hypothesis that $o_{2}$ is an equivalent or better fit than $o_{1}$ i.e. the probability of labelling $o_{2}$ with $w$ is greater than or equal to the probability of labelling $o_{1}$ with $w$.

There are $n_{1}$ annotations for $o_{1}$, in which the object is labelled $x_{1}$ times with $w$. Similarly $o_{2}$ is labelled $x_{2}$ times in $n_{2}$ annotations.

To calculate the p-value I am working out the probability of observing the difference in the proportion of times $o_{1}$ and $o_{2}$ are labelled with $w$, $P(x_{1}/n_{1}-x_{2}/n_{2}\geq d)$, where d is the observed difference. This gives quite a long function, which relies on the actual underlying probability, $p_{1}$, of labelling $o_{1}$ with $w$, so now I suppose I have to find $p_{1}$ which maximises this function?

I feel uncertain that I'm tackling this in the right way, does this seem correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fishers's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) exists for this purpose which calculates the p-value from a contingency table. In this case the null hypothesis is that $o_{1}$ and $o_{2}$ are equally likely to be labelled with the word. It may also be possible to use a [two-proportion z-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_statistic#Common_test_statistics), but this would require a larger dataset.